# wordpress get_tags() returning different number of tags each time it runs

Tags: php, wordpress, function, if-statement, tags

The function below is meant to output six tag images randomly selected from an array to the sidebar, this works apart from a small problem.

The problem - each time the function runs it can out put either 5 or 6 tags, i cannot see why this would be.

The only problem i came across which may be related is the `if( $count >5 )` needs to be set 1 lower that what is needed.

Any help appreciated, 
Cheers

```
function sidebar_tag_cloud_5416__local_agents() {
    $args = array('include' => '183, 
                                184,
                                182,
                                181,
                                180,
                                179,
                                178,
                                177,
                                176,
                                174,
                                173,
                                258,
                                172,
                                171,


                                '); // List in order of eststate agents page
        $alltags = get_tags( $args );
    echo '<ul id=tag-cloud-sidebar>';
        shuffle($alltags);
        $count=0;
        if ($alltags) {
            foreach($alltags as $tag) {
                $count++;

                    // image id is stored as term meta
                $image_id = get_term_meta( $tag->term_id, 'image', true );

                    // image data stored in array, second argument is which image size to retrieve
                $image_data = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $image_id, 'tag_img' );

                    // image url is the first item in the array (aka 0)
                $image = $image_data[0];

                    if ( ! empty( $image ) ) {
                        echo '<li><a  href="'.get_tag_link($tag->term_id).'">';
                        echo '<img title="' . $tag->name . '" alt="' . $tag->name . '" style="width:160px;" src="' . esc_url( $image ) . '"/>';
                        echo '</a></li>';
                    } 

        if( $count >5 ) break;
        }
            echo '</ul>';
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm providing this code for you only to learn by example.
I didn't tested it, so it might require debugging.

```
<?php

function sidebar_tag_cloud_5416__local_agents() {
    // List in order of estate agents page
    $selected_agents = [183, 184, 182, 181, 180, 179, 178, 177, 176, 174, 173, 258, 172, 171];
    $tags_count = 6;

    // Let's select 6 random tag ID's
    $selected_agents = array_intersect_key($selected_agents, array_flip(array_rand($selected_agents, $tags_count)));
    $selected_agents = array('include' => implode(',', $selected_agents));

    // Retrieving tags
    $tags = get_tags($selected_agents);

    // List output
    echo '<ul id="tag-cloud-sidebar">';

    if (!empty($tags)) {
        foreach($tags as $tag) {
            // image id is stored as term meta
            $image_id = get_term_meta($tag->term_id, 'image', true);

            // image data stored in array, second argument is which image size to retrieve
            $image_data = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_id, 'tag_img');

            // image url is the first item in the array (aka 0)
            $image = $image_data[0];

            if (!empty($image)) {
                echo '<li><a href="'. get_tag_link($tag->term_id) . '">';
                echo '<img title="' . $tag->name . '" alt="' . $tag->name . '" style="width: 160px;" src="' . esc_url($image) . '"/>';
                echo '</a></li>';
            }
        }
    }

    echo '</ul>';
}
```

It is better to get 6 random tag ID's before actual tags data retrieval. Also pay attention to the variables naming. Proper names makes your code much more readable. Have a look at the random tags selection algorithm, array_rand do the trick. Best wishes.

Comment: Hi Ivan, I just wanted to thank you for your answer, this is exactly the reason I use StackOverflow one of the most helpful answers I've had to date! thanks again for all the pointers

Comment: I'm happy to hear my answer was helpful for you blackhill24. You've been asking about why sometimes you have output of 5 tags, sometimes 6. I missed that. I reviewed your code again and here is what I think. It might be this condition `if ( ! empty( $image ) ) { }`. According to this if there is no image tag wont be printed.